# refreshApex only work on wired plain parameter?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I always use refreshApex to refresh the condition after some soql action or something else,
I find out that refreshApex only work on plain parameter, for example:

```
@wire(someMethod, {Id: '$recordId'})
result({error, data}) {
    if (data) {...}
    else if (error) {...}
}

@wire(someMethod, {Id: '$recordId'})
dummyResult

handleChange(e) {
    refreshApex(this.result) // this won't work
    refreshApex(this.dummyresult) // this works
}
```

And the amazing part is that if I refresh the dummyResult, all the code inside `if (data)` will be excuted(just what I want), can someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per doc [refreshApex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-result-caching.html?q=refreshapex) method accepts `valueProvisionedByWireService` that means

```
@wire(someMethod, {Id: '$recordId'})
 wiredsomeMethod(result){
  this.dummyResult = result; // Hold on to the provisioned value so we can refresh it later.
   /// your data check and error check logic
  }

handleChange(e) {    
refreshApex(this.dummyresult) 
}
```

> why 'refreshApex(this.result) // this won't work

because you are using [Object destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for your convenience, in this process losing the provisioned value itself